# Why does my grid/flex content shift to the right?

Tags: css, grid

I'm trying to better understand the use of grid/flex for responsive layouts.

I have a grid inside of flex object (flex not shown in code) that I cannot seem to remove the "margin" on the far left. I thought by using grid or flex, I could automatically space the elements equally across the page with the same "margin" on the outside edges.

What is causing the shift of the content to the right?

I think I'm missing something fundamental here.

See image:

[image]

**html:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="parent">
        <li class="child">
            <p class="grandchild"><img  src="https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg?v=47faa659a05e"> </p>
            <p class="grandchild">Text 1 - This needs to go below the first image</p>
        </li>
        <li class="child">
            <p class="grandchild"><img src="https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg?v=47faa659a05e"></p>
            <p class="grandchild">Text 2 - This needs to go below the second image, but in a second column </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**css**

```
img {
        border:3px solid green;
        width:100%;

    }
    li {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
  .parent {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
        grid-gap: 2rem;
        align-content:center;

    }

    .child  {
        margin:0;
        padding:2rem;
    }
    .grandchild {
        border:1px dashed black;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from the default way that ul elements are handled by the browser. List items are automatically indented (when you have bullet points).

Add the following to your `.parent` class;

```css
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
```

Demo;

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  border: 3px solid green;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  align-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.child {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.grandchild {
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="parent">
        <li class="child">
            <p class="grandchild"><img  src="https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg?v=47faa659a05e"> </p>
            <p class="grandchild">Text 1 - This needs to go below the first image</p>
        </li>
        <li class="child">
            <p class="grandchild"><img src="https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg?v=47faa659a05e"></p>
            <p class="grandchild">Text 2 - This needs to go below the second image, but in a second column </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```